# On windows OS and without having iPhone6 or iPadAir 2, How to determine a javascript error on a website?

Tags: javascript, ios8, responsive-design, mobile-safari, iphone-6

I have used many tools online to test website responsibility and mobile emulation but couldn't detect the JavaScript error that prevent the website from loading on my client device. Is there a way to detect the java errors on Safari iOS 8 on windows OS and without owning iPhone 6 or iPad Air 2?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the Developer tools that are built into Safari?

There is a console there where you can see the Javascript errors as well as emulate the iPad.

Comment: I have Safari 5.x.x for windows and yes tested on it including the console .. no javascript errors .. also on chrome, IE, FF developer tools.